# how to get data(name=“string”) from Arraylist in java?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the data from arrayList where name=Telugu.
But I don't know what to do.
Please any one help to get this.

My Code is(in jsp page):

```
try{
    String lang=request.getParameter("languages");
    out.println("know languages are:"+lang);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above languages parameter containe this data:

```
[NamedFacebookType[id=107617475934611 metadata=null name=Telugu type=null],
NamedFacebookType[id=112969428713061 metadata=null name=Hindi type=null],
NamedFacebookType[id=106059522759137 metadata=null name=English type=null]]
```

I want to display know languages are:

```
Telugu
Hindhi
English
```

any one help to get this thank you.

Comment: don't write text as code please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get name(name="string") fromArray in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198411/how-to-get-namename-string-fromarray-in-java)

Comment: thank you.but I deleted my old post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your output it looks like "request.getParameter("languages")" returns a collection of objects of Type "NamedFacebookType".

You need to type cast the output of "request.getParameter("languages")" to that collection type (or its interface/parent class).
ie.

```
List<NamedFacebookType>
```

You then need to iterate that collection and use the appropriate getter method on NamedFacebookType to retrieve the value of "name" field.

The code would probably look something like this :

```
 Object o = request.getParameter("languages");
 if(o instanceof List<?>){
    List<NamedFacebookType > list = (List<NamedFacebookType>) o;
    String []names = new String[list.size()];
    int i=0;
    for(NamedFacebookType namedFacebookType : list){
        names[i]=namedFacebookType.getName();
        i++;
    }

    for(String name:names){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Currently it looks like the output object's (Collection) toString() method is invoked as you are assigning the value to a String object. An hence your output.